# jQuery, JS. Отдельная обработка события в элементах с одинаковым классом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.buy').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.bottom').addClass("clicked");
});

$('.remove').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.bottom').removeClass("clicked");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: #E3E3D8;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0;
  transform: scale(0.95);
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
  box-shadow: 5px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.wrapper .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper .container .top {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/49/80/6f/49806f3f1c7483093855ebca1b8ae2c4.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom {
  width: 200%;
  height: 20%;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom.clicked {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .details {
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(70% - 40px);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .buy {
  float: right;
  width: calc(30% - 2px);
  height: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  border-left: solid thin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .buy i {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #254053;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .buy:hover {
  background: #A6CDDE;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .buy:hover i {
  transform: translateY(5px);
  color: #00394B;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right {
  width: 50%;
  background: #A6CDDE;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  height: 200%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .details {
  padding: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: calc(70% - 40px);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .done {
  width: calc(30% - 2px);
  float: left;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  border-right: solid thin rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  height: 50%;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .done i {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .remove {
  width: calc(30% - 1px);
  clear: both;
  border-right: solid thin rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  height: 50%;
  background: #BC3B59;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background 0.5s;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .remove:hover {
  background: #9B2847;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .remove:hover i {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .remove i {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right:hover .remove,
.wrapper .container .bottom .right:hover .done {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.wrapper .inside {
  z-index: 9;
  background: #92879B;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -70px;
  right: -70px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 200px 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s, border-radius 2s, top 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .inside .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 85px;
  top: 85px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

.wrapper .inside:hover {
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 80%;
}

.wrapper .inside:hover .icon {
  opacity: 0;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}

.wrapper .inside:hover .contents {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.wrapper .inside .contents {
  padding: 5%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: translateY(-200%);
  transition: opacity 0.2s, transform 0.8s;
}

.wrapper .inside .contents table {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .inside .contents h1,
.wrapper .inside .contents p,
.wrapper .inside .contents table {
  color: white;
}

.wrapper .inside .contents p {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Обработка события в элементах с одинаковым классом</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 1</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="buy"><i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="done"><i class="material-icons">done</i></div>
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 1</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="remove"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="icon"><i class="material-icons">info_outline</i></div>
      <div class="contents">
        Описание
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 2</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="buy"><i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="done"><i class="material-icons">done</i></div>
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 2</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="remove"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="icon"><i class="material-icons">info_outline</i></div>
      <div class="contents">
        Описание
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 3</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="buy"><i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="done"><i class="material-icons">done</i></div>
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 3</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="remove"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="icon"><i class="material-icons">info_outline</i></div>
      <div class="contents">
        Описание
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Сейчас при клике на дочерние элементы *buy,remove* выполняется обработка клика для всех элементов *bottom*.
Нужно, чтобы клик обрабатывался **только для одного (своего) родительского элемента** *bottom*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте parents() с селектором ".block", чтобы найти родительский элемент

```js
$('.buy').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.bottom').addClass("clicked");
});

$('.remove').click(function() {
   $(this).parents('.bottom').removeClass("clicked");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: #E3E3D8;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0;
  transform: scale(0.95);
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
  box-shadow: 5px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.wrapper .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper .container .top {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/49/80/6f/49806f3f1c7483093855ebca1b8ae2c4.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom {
  width: 200%;
  height: 20%;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom.clicked {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .details {
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(70% - 40px);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .buy {
  float: right;
  width: calc(30% - 2px);
  height: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  border-left: solid thin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .buy i {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #254053;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .buy:hover {
  background: #A6CDDE;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .buy:hover i {
  transform: translateY(5px);
  color: #00394B;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right {
  width: 50%;
  background: #A6CDDE;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  height: 200%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .details {
  padding: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: calc(70% - 40px);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .done {
  width: calc(30% - 2px);
  float: left;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  border-right: solid thin rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  height: 50%;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .done i {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .remove {
  width: calc(30% - 1px);
  clear: both;
  border-right: solid thin rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  height: 50%;
  background: #BC3B59;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background 0.5s;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .remove:hover {
  background: #9B2847;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .remove:hover i {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .remove i {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right:hover .remove,
.wrapper .container .bottom .right:hover .done {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.wrapper .inside {
  z-index: 9;
  background: #92879B;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -70px;
  right: -70px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 200px 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s, border-radius 2s, top 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .inside .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 85px;
  top: 85px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

.wrapper .inside:hover {
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 80%;
}

.wrapper .inside:hover .icon {
  opacity: 0;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}

.wrapper .inside:hover .contents {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.wrapper .inside .contents {
  padding: 5%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: translateY(-200%);
  transition: opacity 0.2s, transform 0.8s;
}

.wrapper .inside .contents table {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .inside .contents h1,
.wrapper .inside .contents p,
.wrapper .inside .contents table {
  color: white;
}

.wrapper .inside .contents p {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Обработка события в элементах с одинаковым классом</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 1</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="buy"><i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="done"><i class="material-icons">done</i></div>
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 1</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="remove"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="icon"><i class="material-icons">info_outline</i></div>
      <div class="contents">
        Описание
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 2</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="buy"><i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="done"><i class="material-icons">done</i></div>
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 2</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="remove"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="icon"><i class="material-icons">info_outline</i></div>
      <div class="contents">
        Описание
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 3</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="buy"><i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="done"><i class="material-icons">done</i></div>
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 3</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="remove"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="icon"><i class="material-icons">info_outline</i></div>
      <div class="contents">
        Описание
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Постарайтесь добавлять более развёрнутые ответы. Редактировать ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо, должен код работать, но в моём примере не срабатывает.

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробуйте еще раз

Comment: Да, прекрасно работает! (parent - parents )) )

Comment: метод .parent() схож с методом .parents() за тем исключением, что первый перемещается только на один уровень вверх по дереву DOM, а второй возвращает всех предков

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать `stopPropagation`- блокирует передачу события родительскому элементу.
https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $('.block1').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.block').addClass("block-clicked");
  });

  $('.block2').click(function(event) {

    $('.block').removeClass("block-clicked");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @chbronson, прошу прощения, не правильно понял вопрос. `stopPropagation` вам тут не нужно. Всё что вам нужно это просто использовать `parent()`.  Ответ, который дал вам Ербол Кабзитов выше, должен сработать

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.block1').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.block').addClass("block-clicked");
});

$('.block2').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.block').addClass("block-clicked");
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, parents подошёл.

Answer (score 1):

> Нужно, чтобы клик обрабатывался только для одного (своего) родительского элемента block

Предложу вот такой вариант решения...

Суть его в том, чтобы отслеживать клики на родительских элементах и потом все выполнять относительно их.

```js
$('.wrapper').click(function(e) {
  const ob = $(this).find('.bottom')
  const o = $(e.target).parent('.buy, .remove')
  if (o.hasClass('buy')) ob.addClass("clicked")
  if (o.hasClass('remove')) ob.removeClass("clicked")
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: #E3E3D8;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0;
  transform: scale(0.95);
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
  box-shadow: 5px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.wrapper .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper .container .top {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/49/80/6f/49806f3f1c7483093855ebca1b8ae2c4.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom {
  width: 200%;
  height: 20%;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom.clicked {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .details {
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(70% - 40px);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .buy {
  float: right;
  width: calc(30% - 2px);
  height: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  border-left: solid thin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .buy i {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #254053;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .buy:hover {
  background: #A6CDDE;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .left .buy:hover i {
  transform: translateY(5px);
  color: #00394B;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right {
  width: 50%;
  background: #A6CDDE;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  height: 200%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .details {
  padding: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: calc(70% - 40px);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .done {
  width: calc(30% - 2px);
  float: left;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  border-right: solid thin rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  height: 50%;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .done i {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .remove {
  width: calc(30% - 1px);
  clear: both;
  border-right: solid thin rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  height: 50%;
  background: #BC3B59;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background 0.5s;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .remove:hover {
  background: #9B2847;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .remove:hover i {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right .remove i {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper .container .bottom .right:hover .remove,
.wrapper .container .bottom .right:hover .done {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.wrapper .inside {
  z-index: 9;
  background: #92879B;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -70px;
  right: -70px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 200px 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s, border-radius 2s, top 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .inside .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 85px;
  top: 85px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

.wrapper .inside:hover {
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 80%;
}

.wrapper .inside:hover .icon {
  opacity: 0;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}

.wrapper .inside:hover .contents {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.wrapper .inside .contents {
  padding: 5%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: translateY(-200%);
  transition: opacity 0.2s, transform 0.8s;
}

.wrapper .inside .contents table {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .inside .contents h1,
.wrapper .inside .contents p,
.wrapper .inside .contents table {
  color: white;
}

.wrapper .inside .contents p {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Обработка события в элементах с одинаковым классом</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 1</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="buy"><i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="done"><i class="material-icons">done</i></div>
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 1</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="remove"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="icon"><i class="material-icons">info_outline</i></div>
      <div class="contents">
        Описание
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 2</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="buy"><i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="done"><i class="material-icons">done</i></div>
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 2</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="remove"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="icon"><i class="material-icons">info_outline</i></div>
      <div class="contents">
        Описание
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 3</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="buy"><i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="done"><i class="material-icons">done</i></div>
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Номер 3</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="remove"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="icon"><i class="material-icons">info_outline</i></div>
      <div class="contents">
        Описание
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я прекрасно вижу, что ваш код рабочий. Но в моём случае почему-то не срабатывает.

Comment: @chbronson, тогда тебе имеет смысл подредактировать свой тестовый пример, дабы он был больше похож на твою реальную ситуацию. Тогда и я смогу предложить более точное решение. ;)

Comment: @chbronson, я изменил свой пример, смотри.

Comment: Тоже отлично работает! "Галочку" можно ставить только одному ответу?

Comment: @chbronson, "галка" только одна на всех... :) Выбери ответ, который тебе больше понравился - ему и поставь.